# If I renew my distribution certificate, do I need to renew my notification certificates as well?

Tags: ios, xcode

My distribution certificate will expire in about a month. I renewed it recently, do I need to renew my Apple Push Services certificate as well?

I am asking this because after I renewed my distribution certificate, I am not receiving any remote notifications on an XCode build.

Comment: Yes, You need to renew/update Push Notification certificates as well.

Comment: @BhavikModi Got it. I'll try that. You can submit it as an answer and I'll accept if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to renew all the certificates which are expired or going to expire for Distribution/Development process.

You should have to renew your APNS certificate based on its expiration If the expiration date of both of the certificate Distribution and APNS is the same.